# area inside the curve $\phi(t)=(a(2\cos(t)-\cos(2t)),a(2\sin(t)-\sin(2t)))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I tried using
$$(1)A=\int_0^{2\pi}x(t)y'(t)\,dt=\int_0^{2\pi}a(2\cos(t)-\cos(2t))a(2\cos(t)-2\cos(2t))\,dt=6\pi a^2$$
and
$$(2)A=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}r^2(t)\,dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}(a(2\cos(t)-\cos(2t)))^2+(a(2\sin(t)-\sin(2t)))^2\,dt=5\pi a^2 $$

but I get two different answers. Shouldn't they be the same?

This is a plot, blue is $r(t)=\sqrt{x^2(t)+y^2(t)}$(polar coordinates) and red $\phi(t)=(x(t),y(t))$[image]

Comment: Your question is not about area but about what your curve is.right?

Comment: yes, I don't know why they are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have confused $t$, the parameter for your curve, and $\theta$, the independent variable to depict the angle a point makes with the x-axis. The curve in parametric form is

$$r(t) = \sqrt{x(t)^2 + y(t)^2}, \theta(t) = \arctan\left(\frac{y(t)}{x(t)}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Cartesian parametrization is right. Correct polar parametrization:

The polar radius should be

$$\sqrt {5-2 \cos t}$$

and polar angle

$$ \tan^{-1}\dfrac{2\sin t -\sin 2t}{2 \cos t - \cos 2t}$$

$t$ is a parameter, not polar angle !

Just like in an ellipse

$$ x= a \cos t,y= a \sin t $$
$t$ is not polar angle but an eccentric ***anomaly*** angle,

in this case also if you can identify what this $t$ is other than polar angle, and plot it in the graph, your geometrical recognition would be the better for it..